# Unexpected reactivity in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

For college I have to create a Vue.js app that manages home automation. The backend is a simple json server. This server contains data for each room including time slots.

Time slots determine the value of a certain element in a room between two points in time (the temperature for example)

I am using a v-data-table to display each time slot for a specific room, for a specific element.
Since the value of the time slots that correspond to the position of the curtains is a boolean I want to replace true or false with open or closed in the table.
I tried to do this by passing the array of timeslots through the array map function however this caused some strange behavior.

First of all: the time slot value is always 'open' in the new array, also when the value was false.
Secondly: the time slot values actually change to 'open' inside my json server. I have no idea why this happens since I thought the map function returns an entirely new array instead of changing the current one.

The data table:

```
<v-data-table
        v-if="room"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="room.timeslots.filter(timeslot => {return timeslot.element == 'cur'}).map(timeslot => {if(timeslot.value) {timeslot.value='open'} else {timeslot.value='gesloten'} return timeslot;})"
        :custom-sort="customSort"
        hide-default-footer
        class="elevation-1 ma-5"
      >
        <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
          <v-icon @click="deleteTimeslot(item.id)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </template>
        <template slot="no-data">
            Voor dit element zijn er nog geen tijdssloten ingesteld.
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

Sample data from my json server:

```
{
    rooms: [
        {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Bureau",
      "description": "Ssssssst, hier wordt gewerkt!",
      "temp": 22,
      "curtainsOpen": true,
      "volume": 11,
      "light": 0,
      "floor": 1,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 350,
      "height": 350,
      "timeslots": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "start": "12:00",
          "end": "13:00",
          "value": "21",
          "element": "temp"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "start": "03:20",
          "end": "04:20",
          "value": true,
          "element": "cur"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "start": "14:00",
          "end": "15:00",
          "value": false,
          "element": "cur"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please explain this behavior and / or tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering why the map method was behaving like a mutating method while it is actually a non-mutating method.

This is because I was using it as a mutating method, this is of course bad practice.

Heres a working solution:

```
<v-data-table
   v-if="room"
   :headers="headers"
   :items="room.timeslots.filter(timeslot => {return timeslot.element == 'cur'}).map(timeslot => {return {...timeslot, value: timeslot.value ? 'open' : 'closed'}})"
   :custom-sort="customSort"
   hide-default-footer
   class="elevation-1 ma-5"
>
   <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
        <v-icon @click="deleteTimeslot(item.id)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
   </template>
   <template slot="no-data">
        Voor dit element zijn er nog geen tijdssloten ingesteld.
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```